# Send PHP HTML message to GMAIL

Tags: php, email

I know there is a lot of questions like this with a good answer on this site but I can't get any one of them to work for me.

I managed to do an email code verification, works fine on other email providers but is not working on Gmail. I have searched on Google a lot of solutions for my problem but I can't find any solution for me.

Here is my code:

```
$to = $email;
    $subject = "¡Aquí está tu código para restablecer tu contraseña!";
    $message = '
        <html lang="es">
                <p>Hemos recibido una solicitud para restablecer tu contraseña. El asistente de restablecimiento de contraseña te solicitará un código, el cual es:</p>
                <h3 style="text-align:center" class="teal">'.$codigo.'</h3>            
        </html>
    ';
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <webmaster@myemail.com>' . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I can't get the code to work with Gmail, it is not even in SPAM folder. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with valid html and not the html above?

Comment: I hope you are not trying on localhost and have you tried to print the value of `$email`

Comment: RamRider: No, I haven't tried with valid HTML, I'll try it.
Danyal Sendeelo: No, is not localhost, is a web page online.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue in my local development area. And its resolved using you need to change/check in your php.ini for mail confirmation section.

Comment: Unfortunately, my hosting plan has blocked the access to the php.ini file, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I copied your PHP codes and executed it, there was no problem. Sending email was successful, so it does not depend on PHP codes.

Could you check the followings.

- If you wanted to sent a email through postfix or sendmail, could you check /var/log/maillog. There might be a hint.
- If you wanted to send to a gmail smtp server directly, you have to change a port number to 587 or 465 as a submission port, or specifying google user and password are necessary.

Comment: Can you help me with that? I don't know too much of PHP
Thanks!